# Creating a Arcmap tool that buffers and then intersects

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy, arcmap

Im trying to create a tool that buffers a feature class (polygon) and then intersects the buffer output layer with a point shapefile. When I run the tool the buffer analysis runs and completes but the intersect analysis does not. The error message is

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000732: *(my buffer output layer & point shapefile)* does not exist or is not supported
>   Failed to execute (Intersect).

All my layers are loaded in my arcmpap so I am not sure why it does that.

```
import arcpy

in_Path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # first parameter in the interactive tool
out_Path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # second parameter in the interactive tool

bufferDistance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)# third parameter in the interactive tool

result_buffer = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_Path, out_Path, bufferDistance,"FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "") #the parameters to able compute the tool
# ^^ assign variable for the buffer analysis tool 

in_CitiesShapefile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)# fourth parameter in the interactive tool

out_CitiesWithinBuffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) # fifth parameter in the interactive tool

arcpy.Intersect_analysis([out_Path, in_CitiesShapefile], out_CitiesWithinBuffer,"ALL", "", "INPUT") #the parameters to able compute the tool
```

Answer (score 0):

This error often comes up when there is a problem with file/folder paths.

I'd check the parameters that take paths for the following:

- Misspelled folder names
- Using backslashes instead of forward slashes
- Having spaces in the path names

This [esri kb article](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35151) might help.